# Threadpool Deadlock: designing against or detecting

Tags: java, threadpool, deadlock

I hope this isn't overly broad; my question is "How do I design a service with multiple Threadpools which can't deadlock itself?".

I own a web service which fans out to 100s of threads on a single user request, to perform data aggregation with low latency.  There are a number of ExecutorServices wrapping fixed-thread pools sprinkled throughout my service, and I need help solving an interesting way this can create deadlock.

I have a threadpool `A` which is used to hold Threads making network requests, and another threadpool `B` which is used to hold their "owning" threads; aggregation bits of business-logic which might fan out into a handful of requests.  Additionally, threads in `B` occasionally submit bits of work to threadpool `B`, when an aggregation can be done by aggregating 3 simpler sub-aggregations.

This pattern is the problem.  Let's consider a style of request `x` submitted to `B` which causes an additional request `x'` to be submitted to `B`.  Let's also consider `B` is a fixed thread pool of 50 threads.  When 50 requests of type `x` come in at the same time, all threads in `B` are used to handle these requests.  All of them submit their `x1` to `B`, which sits in the queue waiting for a thread.  And then all processing of all requests sits in deadlock for 60 seconds until a timeout is hit and the `x` requests all return Exceptions.

Things I've considered/tried:

- Tweak numbers.  Maximum users who can connect is 50, threads in `B` is 100.  Prevents the problem, but seems like a hack that will break when another dev tweaks unrelated numbers in a year and no one can figure out why we lock up once a week under load.  I want to solve this in the design.
- `B` submits fanned out work to `B'`, a new threadpool.  Doesn't work because this fan-out can potentially go multiple steps (do I create `B''`, `B'''`, ...?)
- `B` has no max threads.  Possibly acceptable, seems dangerous.
- Another model (more callbackish?) where threads don't submit and wait for the same unit of work; rather they submit work and submit a "callback" into the 
  "run-after" pool.  This way nothing can wait for something in its own pool.  Is there precedent, is this a good idea?
- Collapse all thread pools together and remove the max?

Comment: I think this is a very good question. You should try something more event-oriented (or callbackish as you mentioned). You could try threadpools, event-queues, [actors](http://akka.io/), or even with the amazing [lmax ringbuffer disruptor](https://github.com/LMAX-Exchange/disruptor) for very short-lived tasks. I recommend you use a foundation library to accomplish this, such as [RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava) or [Reactor](http://spring.io/blog/2013/05/13/reactor-a-foundation-for-asynchronous-applications-on-the-jvm/). Just avoid threads, your requirements point somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "more callbackish" answer seems like it'd mostly be solved for you via the [CompletionStage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html) API in Java 8 - the lack of a "runAfterAllAsync" method means you may have to do some external work to get something to happen after your group of 3 subtasks, but this is where I'd start to look.  [This tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jvmc2/index.html) has an example that may be of some help.